I use the package blackhole_vpn in flutter.it doesn't work with the example in pub dev website
I create a new flutter project and I use two packages blackhole_vpn: ^1.0.0 and android_package_manager: ^0.7.1
I do all configurations are in Read me explanation for each package with the code:
When I run the app. The app work but the results is Vpn permission not granted.
Also, I add all permissions in Android manifest. Can you suggest any way to solve that?
https://pub.dev/packages/blackhole_vpn/example
I explain all things in the top. I want suggestions please. Thanks

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
